# Apache : URL Redirection when using Virtual Hosts

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, virtualhost

I have 2 domain with 2 differents registar, the problem is I would like to to point them in my Dedicated server with the same IP, so I have used  Virtual Hosts with this configuration :

My httpd.conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
ServerAdmin webmaster@xxxxxxxx.com
ServerName www.xxxxxxxx.com
DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 "http://xxxxxxxx.com/error"
</VirtualHost>
# Virtual host Virtual Host 2
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/www/html/yyyyyyyy/
ServerAdmin webmaster@yyyyyyyy.com
ServerName www.yyyyyyyy.com
ServerAlias yyyyyyyy.com
RewriteEngine  on
ErrorDocument 404 "http://yyyyyyyy.com"

</VirtualHost>
```

And I changed the Ip of the two domain to the server IP, this has work fine for the first website but for the second one , when entring the URL it changes automaticaly to this url :

```
www.xxxxxxxx.com/yyyyyyyy/
```

In other terms, the url is changed.

What I need to do to not permit the rewrite of the URL of the second website.

Please Help...

Comment: Why don't you place yyyyy on its own folder `/home/www/yyyyyyyy/` instead of inside xxxxx?

Comment: Yeah good idea , I just tried that but when entreing the second URL this has pointed to "http://xxxxxxxx.com/error"

Comment: Remove the ErrorDocument and any .htaccess inside yyyy for the time being and restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this in Cpanel not in httpd.conf

on the receiving(hosting) server select the addon domain and enter the domain you wish to accept and the directory it should point to

then change the IP address in your DNS A records of your redirect domains to point to your hosting server (make sure to copy the old IP address just in case you need to roll back, I recommend a screenshot)

Comment: Note, your the redirect folder should be in the htdocs folder

Comment: That is, if he is using or have cPanel available, looking at his virtualhost does not seem to have cPanel.

Comment: I don't have CPanel but I have webmin I can create virtualhost  with webmin I have changed the IP address for the second website and it redirect to the server but the problem as I said is the url changed. I will try to create 2 folders in www/html and point each site in one of them hope this will work

Comment: if you don't have CPanel, you can try ModRewrite, I normally do it in .htaccess, but it should work in httpd.conf as well

`RewriteEngine on

RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower

RewriteCond %{lowercase:%{HTTP_HOST}} ^www\.([^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /home/%1/www$1`

Comment: @prix I don't know how to tell if someone has cPanel by looking at httpd.conf can you link me to that resource?

Comment: @Philippe that's from experience, as the cPanel have a very peculiar virtualhost setup.